# How to add Availabity set to virtual machine in azure through python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I am using python script to create virtual machine. I am able to create virtul machine. Just wanted to add availabilty set feature.

<< some snip >>

```
resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
```

# Create Resource group
    print('\nCreate Resource Group')
    resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, {'location':LOCATION})

```
# Create a storage account
print('\nCreate a storage account')
storage_async_operation = storage_client.storage_accounts.create(
    GROUP_NAME,
    STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    {
        'sku': {'name': 'standard_lrs'},
        'kind': 'storage',
        'location': LOCATION
    }
)
storage_async_operation.wait()

# Create a NIC
nic = create_nic(network_client)
```

<<>>

just looking for function which can creat availabiltyset. And  i can attach to multiple vms

Comment: so what have you tried besides pasting this example from documentation? what doesnt work?

Comment: @4c74356b41   I am not able to figure out how to create availabilty set. I have give some tried like. compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
        GROUP_NAME,
        AVAILABLITY_SET_NAME,                                                                                                                                                     
        {
            'platformFaultDomainCount': '3',
            'platformUpdateDomainCount': '20',
            'location': LOCATION
        } but it is also failing.

Answer (score 2):

AvailabilitySet has it's own create operation:
http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.AvailabilitySetsOperations.create_or_update

So your code should look like:

```
compute_client.availability_sets.create_or_update(
    group_name,
    availability_set_name,
    availability_set_parameters
)
```

Comment: Availabiltyset creation part is working fine. How can we assign this set to virtual machine creatioLn?

Comment: Use the "availability_set" parameter in the "virtual_machines.create_or_update". http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.create_or_update